# Kill child processes when parent powershell process is killed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell

My use case is the following:

In visual studio, on debug I start powershell and feed a script that along with a couple of actions, it starts the project executable like so:

```
&$exeToStart $exeParams | Out-Host
```

This works nicely when I run the script from a powershell console. My problems start when I stop debugging via the VS stop icon which essentially kills the powershell process that runs this script thus leaving a hanging exe process which I have to manually kill afterwards.

So, my question is how to ensure that when visual studio kills the parent powershell process, the child process is also killed with it?

Comment: I add a way to have it work efficiently in Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

You will find here under something that do the "job". The code here under is a proof of concept. You have to put it in a function and call it at the begining of all your embeded scripts.

```
#TestJob.ps1
$CreateJobObjectSignature = @"
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class ClsNativ
{
  public enum JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS
  {
    AssociateCompletionPortInformation = 7,
    BasicLimitInformation = 2,
    BasicUIRestrictions = 4,
    EndOfJobTimeInformation = 6,
    ExtendedLimitInformation = 9,
    SecurityLimitInformation = 5,
    GroupInformation = 11
  }

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
  {
    public Int64 PerProcessUserTimeLimit;
    public Int64 PerJobUserTimeLimit;
    public UInt32 LimitFlags;
    public UIntPtr MinimumWorkingSetSize;
    public UIntPtr MaximumWorkingSetSize;
    public UInt32 ActiveProcessLimit;
    public Int64 Affinity;
    public UInt32 PriorityClass;
    public UInt32 SchedulingClass;
  }


  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  struct IO_COUNTERS
  {
    public UInt64 ReadOperationCount;
    public UInt64 WriteOperationCount;
    public UInt64 OtherOperationCount;
    public UInt64 ReadTransferCount;
    public UInt64 WriteTransferCount;
    public UInt64 OtherTransferCount;
  }

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  struct JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
  {
    public JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION BasicLimitInformation;
    public IO_COUNTERS IoInfo;
    public UIntPtr ProcessMemoryLimit;
    public UIntPtr JobMemoryLimit;
    public UIntPtr PeakProcessMemoryUsed;
    public UIntPtr PeakJobMemoryUsed;
  }

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  public static extern IntPtr CreateJobObject(IntPtr lpJobAttributes, string lpName);

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern bool AssignProcessToJobObject(IntPtr hJob, IntPtr hProcess);

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern bool SetInformationJobObject(IntPtr hJob, JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS JobObjectInfoClass, IntPtr lpJobObjectInfo, uint cbJobObjectInfoLength);

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();


  private const UInt32 JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE = 0x2000;
  public ClsNativ()
  {
    IntPtr hJob = CreateJobObject(IntPtr.Zero, "JobName");

    JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION info = new JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION();
    info.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;

    JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION extendedInfo = new JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION();
    extendedInfo.BasicLimitInformation = info;

    int length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION));
    IntPtr extendedInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(extendedInfo, extendedInfoPtr, false);

    SetInformationJobObject(hJob, JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS.ExtendedLimitInformation, extendedInfoPtr, (uint)length);

    IntPtr hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    bool blRc = AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, hProcess);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(extendedInfoPtr);
  }
}
"@



Add-Type -TypeDefinition $CreateJobObjectSignature 
$a = New-Object ClsNativ

& notepad.exe
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\windows\system32\calc.exe"

Read-Host "Push return key !"
```

**The concept** : I create a job,a [system object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects), not a sceduled job nor a PowerShell job. I configure it with "JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE", so that if the last handle of the job is closed, then all the processes inside are closed. Then I assign the PowerShell process to the job. All the sub process belongs to the job and as the only job handle is inside the PowerShell procecess, when this one die, all the others disapears. So it does the trick.

I test it on a **Seven** with a **x64** PowerShell. The trouble is that a job can't be added to a process that already belongs to a job (this the case in normal start of VS 2010)

I test it on a **Windows 8** with a **x64** PowerShell.

Here is the way to test it :

```
powershell -file "C:\temp\TestJob.ps1"
```

---

Using Windows Seven, when you start Visual studio normaly, it's already inside a job as you can see in the following sreenshot :

[image]

But if you start Visual Studio 2010 using WMI like this :

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -path win32_process -name create -argumentlist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

It no longer belongs to a Job :

[image]

So then , when you start a PowerShell on debug with sub processes, theey are all stopped when PowerShell is stopped :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I doubt Visual Studio has a way of terminating all child processes when you stop debugging.

One solution would be to run a PowerShell script to clean up..  You could use the ParentProcessId property on the Win32_Process CimInstance.  It might look something like (using PowerShell V3):

```
 Get-CimInstance win32_process |
    ? { (Get-Process -id $_.ParentProcessId -ea Ignore) -eq $null } |
    Stop-Process -WhatIf
```

This would return a list of processes where the parent process no longer exists.  Note that to use this robustly, you need to filter on processes you know you started.  For example, if I tried to kill all of the process returned by the above command, I'd try to kill csrss.exe, wininit.exe, and other processes that I wouldn't want killed.

You could probably even create a macro to run in Visual Studio to stop debugging and run your PowerShell script.  The Package Console uses PowerShell, see http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/using-nuget-powershell-to-replace-missing-macros-in-dev-11 for some ideas what this might look like.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell script:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "Name like 'myprocess.exe'" | ? { (Get-Process -id $_.ParentProcessId -ea Ignore) -eq $null } | Select-Object ProcessId | ? { Stop-Process $_.ProcessId -Force }
```

This is the Powershell script that worked for me after reading Jason's answer.